# Update database via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

For the life of me I cannot get get LINQ to actually update a record set. At the present moment all I am succeeding in doing is adding a new row to the database.

To explain the code below,
I am looping through a column witch holds dates. `filterFrom` is the date to start the `foreach` loop and `filterTo` the end date in the loop. All which is done through the `DateRange` method. If code for that is needed please say so, but the `foreach` loop itself is working the way it should.

Then what I am trying to do is test to see if the date for the record set exists
via LINQ, `p.Date_Data == day` and if columns `p.Time_Data_2` and `p.Time_Data_1` are not null values ,to then update the column `Info_Data`. However what is happening is that I am adding a new row with just the the data from the query and not updating the existing data.

```
foreach (DateTime day in DateRange(filterFrom, filterTo))
{
    if (sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Any(p => p.Date_Data == day && p.Staff_No == SelectedEmployee && p.Time_Data_1 != null && p.Time_Data_2 != null && p.Info_Data == null))
    {    
        Staff_Time_TBL updateRow = new Staff_Time_TBL
        {                            
            Info_Data = "myValue",                            
        };    
        sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.InsertOnSubmit(updateRow);
    }
    sql.SubmitChanges();
}
```

How could I amend this so that it updates the data and not create a new row of data in the database?

Comment: In your `if` statement you are calling `InsertOnSubmit` method, I believe you have to call `update` method. This is what I understood from your `question`.Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Chaitanya, the `if ` statement is just there to test that the columns in question are not `null` values, if they are go to the next row of data. I don't believe that is the problem here. What happens is the query inside the `if` statement is adding data in a new row and not just updating existing data. Or maybe that is where I am not understanding this???

Comment: Why are you expecting `UPDATE`'s when you are only `new`ing up new objects and saving them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if the record exists, but you should also try to retrieve it in order to update it, so you should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of that `Any`.

```
var staffTime = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Date_Data == day && 
    p.Staff_No == SelectedEmployee && p.Time_Data_1 != null && p.Time_Data_2 != null &&
    p.Info_Data == null);

if (staffTime != null)
{
    staffTime.Info_Data = "myValue";
    sql.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This does not seems to work for me?

Comment: @KyloRen - Can you put a breakpoint and see if `staffTime` is found (not null)?

Comment: Yes it is returning a null value.

Comment: The if statement seems to be working as it should and entering when I need it to. For some reason it is just not updating the database?

Comment: You should check the database, probably there isn't any record to satisfy those requirements, so there's nothing for you to update...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong , but if this `p => p.Date_Data == day` is returning true should that record not exist? Ie. it matches the same date?

Comment: No, you are correct. I was updating nothing, I needed to stipulate another criteria in the query. I will update my question, so could you update the answer to suit. This solved my problem. Thanks for the help. Up vote for the great help.

Comment: This should also be in the statement, `p.Staff_No == SelectedEmployee`, cheers